# i only want to have array without null values (i have used empety(), isset(), is_null); below is my array and code that i have implemented toget array

Tags: php, arrays

Below array is formed when i fetch data from xsl sheet
i have used empty(), isset(), is_null but all are not working

bellow is my code

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($newSheetData); $i++){

if($newSheetData[$i][0] == ''){

unset($newSheetData[$i]);

}else{

//unset($newSheetData[$i]);

}

}
```

This is my output:

```
<pre/>Array
(

[0] => Array

(

[0] => quetion

[1] => option1

[2] => option2

)

[1] => Array

(

[0] => What

[1] => a

[2] => b

)

[2] => Array

(

[0] => now

[1] => a

[2] => b

)

[3] => Array

(

[0] => What

[1] => a

[2] => b

)

[4] => Array

(

[0] =>  

[1] =>  

[2] => 

)

[5] => Array

(

[0] =>  

[1] =>  

[2] =>    

)

[6] => Array

(

[0] =>  

[1] =>  

[2] =>  

)

[7] => Array

(

[0] =>  

[1] =>  

[2] => 

)

[8] => Array

(

[0] =>  

[1] =>  

[2] =>  

)

[9] => Array

(

[0] =>  

[1] =>  

[2] => 

)

[10] => Array

(

[0] =>  

[1] =>  

[2] => 

)

)

)
```

**i want this type of array**

```
Array (

[0] => Array

(

[0] => quetion

[1] => option1

[2] => option2

)

[1] => Array

(

[0] => What

[1] => a

[2] => b

)

[2] => Array

(

[0] => now

[1] => a

[2] => b

)

[3] => Array

(

[0] => What

[1] => a

[2] => b

)
```

Comment: [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please use some common sense and the correct tags. This has nothing to do with CakePHP at all. I've edited the tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($newSheetData as $key => $value) {
    $dataFiltred = array_filter($value, function($var) {
        if ($var === 0 || $var === '0' || !empty($var)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
    if (empty($dataFiltred)) {
        unset($newSheetData[$key]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: thank you but it is giving me an empty keys array <pre/>Array
(
    [0] =>  
    [1] =>  
    [2] =>  
    [3] =>  
    [4] =>  
    [5] =>  
)